# Questions array insert to mysql with loop

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a form with multiple questions one of which uses an array for the questions and has a dropdown for the answers. I am only getting the last question appear in my database instead of the array of questions that should appear. I know I have to loop my inserts some how but I am getting stuck so would love some pointing in the correct direction.

```
$questionarray = array("Was the customer's .......?", "Was the advisor's ....?", "Did the advisor .....?", "Did the advisor .......?");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){       
    mysql_real_escape_string($question = $_POST['question']); $answer = $_POST['answer'];
}
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database` (`question`, `answer`) VALUES ('".$question."', '".$answer."');") or die(mysql_error());
```

My looping question:

```
<?php foreach ( $questionarray as $question ){                          
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $question ?><input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?php echo $question ?>" /></td>
                        <td><select name="answer">                              
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                            <option value="NA">NA</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

So the question loops and the answer is going to have to go with each question also.

Thanks for any help